# dynamic import typescript express

Tags: typescript, express, import

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const env: string = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

export const cnf = async () => {
  const data = await import('./config.' + env);
  console.log('data');
  return data;
};
```

from my app.ts

```
import * as confgg from '../../config';
class App {
  public app: express.Application;
  private host: string = process.env.IP || process.env.ADMIN_HOST || cnf.get('web.host');
  private port: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || parseInt(process.env.ADMIN_PORT, 10) || cnf.get('web.port');

  private mysql = MySql.getInstance();

  constructor(private readonly config: AppConfig) {
    this.app = express();
    this.initializeInfoLoggingHandling();
    console.log(confgg)
  }
```

this console.log printing

```
{ cnf: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

but it's supposed to print some array.
I am just trying to load my configuration dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

> this console.log printing
> { cnf: [Function (anonymous)] }
>
> but it's supposed to print some array.

It's supposed to be showing exactly that, because you're exporting a function using a named export, but importing the module namespace object, which has a property for each export. So you're seeing an object (the module namespace object) with a property (`cnf`) which refers to a function (the `async` function you're exporting).

If you want to use dynamic import and make your export the result of that dynamic import, you need to make your module wait for it with [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await):

`config.ts`:

```typescript
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const env: string = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// Top-level await waits for the import to finish
const data = await import('./config.' + env);
console.log('data');

export default data; // See note below
```

then import the default rather than the module namespace object:

```typescript
import confgg from '../../config';
```

You haven't shown what the contents of your `config.development` etc. files are, but `data` will be a module namespace object for the configuration information, you may want to export one of its properties instead.

---

Note that top-level `await` is still just a proposal, though it's very far along and present in popular JavaScript engines and module bundlers.

Comment: FWIW, I go into JavaScript module import and export, dynamic import, and top-level `await` in Chapters 13 and 19 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.